# How many subgroups of order 6 of abelian groups of order 24 are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups we can see that it can either be isomorphic to:

$$C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 $$

or

$$C_2 \times C_4 \times C_3 $$

or

$$C_8 \times C_3$$
I feel like this is important, but how do I find the subgroups?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many elements of order 6 are there?

Comment: in the first one 3, in the second and third ones 2-2 each.

Comment: I counted more in the first two. For example in the first one, an element $(a,b,c,d) \in C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3$ will have order 6 if and only if $d$ has order 3 and $(a,b,c)$ has order 2. There are two elements of $C_3$ with order 3. How many elements of $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ have order 2?

Comment: oh, I see. So there are 3 elements in $$C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2  $$ of order 2, right? But $$C_2=<c>$$ and $$c^2$$ and $$c^1$$ are both of order 3? So $$C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 $$ must have 6.

Comment: There are more than 3 elements in $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ with order 2. If you are having trouble seeing them, try writing out all 8 elements of $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and check each one.

Comment: $C_8 \times C_3 \cong C_{24}$,  $C_4 \times C_3 \cong C_{12}$, and $C_2\times C_3 \cong C_6$. (all conclusions from the fact that $C_n\times C_m \cong C_{nm}$ if and only if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$

Comment: That simply means that the 3 distinct abelian groups of order 24 (which is correct) can also be identified as $C_2 \times C_2\times C_6$, $C_2 \times C_{12}$, and $C_{24}$

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is an abelian group of order $8$ and $b$ is a generator of $C_2$, then for $h \in H, (h,b^k)$ has order $6$ if and only if $|h| = 2$ and $k = 1,2$.

If $|h| = 2$, then: $(h,b)^6 = (h^6,b^6) = ((h^2)^3,(b^3)^2) = (e^3,e^2) = (e,e)$.

But $(h,b)^2 = (h^2,b^2) = (e,b^2) \neq (e,e)$, and $(h,b)^3 = (h^3,b^3) = (h^2h,e) = (h,e) \neq (e,e)$.

This shows $(h,b)$ has order $6$, and the proof for $(h,b^2)$ is similar.

On the other hand, suppose $(h,b^k)$ has order $6$. Then $h^6 = e$, and $b^{6k} = e$. Thus $h$ has order $1,2,3$ or $6$.

Since $|h|$ must divide $8$, only $|h| = 1,2$ are possible. If $|h| = 1$, then $h = e$, and $(e,b^k)^3 = (e^3,b^{3k}) = (e,(b^3)^k) = (e,e^k) = (e,e)$, so $(e,b^k)$ can have order $3$ at most.

Hence $|h| = 2$. But $(h,b^0)^2 = (h,e)^2 = (h^2,e^2) = (e,e)$, and so has only order $2$. This concludes the proof.

So the number of elements of order $6$ in $H \times C_2$ is double the number of elements of order $2$ in $H$.

If $H \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$, every non-identity element has order $2$ (this can easily be seen from the fact that $(a,b,c,d)^2 = (a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2) = (e,e,e,e)$). . If $H \cong C_8$, only one element has order $2$. It falls to you to count the elements of order $2$ in $C_4 \times C_2$ (you may find it easier to eliminate the identity and the elements of order $4$, what's left-over must have order $2$).

Note that every abelian group of order $6$ has exactly two elements of order $6$ (both generators, which are inverses of each other). So every inverse-pair of elements of order $6$ accounts for one subgroup of order $6$ (in an abelian group).